# Disable alarm clock sound for events

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell-extension

I'm using the Online Accounts feature to sync my google calendar to gnome calendar, and keep noticing the alarm clock sound. It also doesn't seem to match up with the event time and or any consistent like '2 mins before'.

So I would like to disable it completely and just rely on the visual pop-up.

Tried:

- Disabling sound alerts for Evolution Alarm Notify
- Disabling sound alerts for calendar
- Turning off notifications for cal, reminders etc

On Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Did you disabled sound [notifications on Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6aJV.png)?

Comment: @Kaigo we would request you to respond to the comments or answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't really reproduce this but you may mute system sounds.[image: screeshot]